# SQL: Count instances of one attribute per another

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm learning SQL and have set what seemed a simple task.  I have a list of fictional people who have been given an intelligence rating from 1 (a bit dim) to 5 (Einstein watch out!), and whose gender is identified:

```
name  gender intelligence
Bob   Male   4
Jane  Female 5
Gary  Male   1
Linda Female 2
Stan  Male   2
Barb  Female 4
... list truncated...
```

What I would like to do is report, "for each level of intelligence, how many males and how many females are there?  For the sample, I'm looking for something like this:

```
Intelligence    Male    Female
1               1       0
2               1       1
3               0       0
4               1       1
5               0       1
```

It's easy enough to come up with a list of each level of intelligence:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(intelligence) from table ORDER BY intelligence;
```

Now my general-purpose programming side says to construct a loop around that, but that both seems wrong and isn't (apparently) simple to do.  Or, at least, not simple enough for my novice capabilities.  Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?  Is this genuinely harder than I think it is?  I've learned about query basics - IN, LIKE, HAVING, CASE, nested SELECT, etc.

My more general goal is to be able to answer questions like, "For each type of X found in the table, how many of each type of Y are there?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select intelligence, sum(gender = 'Male') as num_males, sum(gender = 'Female') as num_females
from t
group by intelligence;
```

SQLite treats boolean expressions as numbers, with "1" for true and "0" for false.  In other databases, you would typically need an explicit `case`:

```
select intelligence,
       sum(case when gender = 'Male' then 1 else 0 end) as num_males,
       sum(case when gender = 'Female' then 1 else 0 end) as num_females
from t
group by intelligence;
```

Of course, this also works in SQLite, but it is more verbose.

Comment: Thank you.  That was really fast and works very well.  As a follow-up, is it possible to abstract the portion where gender is hard-coded?  There might be cases, for example, where I'm tracking, say, generational groups by country and I want to know how many Gen Z, Millennials, Gen X, etc are in each country.  If a new country appears, I have to add a new summed case to the query.  Can that be made dynamic?

Again, thank you.  That answers the question quite well and shows me a couple of syntaxes I didn't know about.

Comment: @Andrew . . . In general, that requires dynamic SQL is and requires a more complicated solution.

Comment: Thank you again.  The explanation is greatly appreciated.